# Need to get the values from ansible json stdout and put them in to a list

Tags: ansible

Given this input:

```
"stdout_lines": [  
            "{",  
            "    \"apiVersion\": \"v1\",",  
            "    \"items\": [",  
            "        {",  
            "            \"apiVersion\": \"v1\",",  
            "            \"kind\": \"Namespace\",",  
            "            \"metadata\": {",  
            "                \"annotations\": {",  
            "                    \"kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration\": \"{\\\"apiVersion\\\":\\\"v1\\\",\\\"kind\\\":\\\"Namespace\\\",\\\"metadata\\\":{\\\"annotations\\\":{},\\\"labels\\\":{\\\"istio-injection\\\":\\\"enabled\\\"},\\\"name\\\":\\\"test-rewards\\\"}}\\n\"",  
            "                },",  
            "                \"creationTimestamp\": \"2018-09-25T23:45:37Z\",",  
            "                \"labels\": {",  
            "                    \"istio-injection\": \"enabled\"",  
            "                },",  
            "                \"name\": \"test-rewards\",",  
            "                \"resourceVersion\": \"7399723\",",  
            "                \"selfLink\": \"/api/v1/namespaces/test-rewards\",",  
            "                \"uid\": \"1a8e3-c11d-11e8-9986-8acd436f34\"",  
            "            },",  
            "            \"spec\": {",  
            "                \"finalizers\": [",  
            "                    \"kubernetes\"",  
            "                ]",  
            "            },",  
            "            \"status\": {",  
            "                \"phase\": \"Active\"",  
            "            }",  
            "        },",  
            "        {",  
            "            \"apiVersion\": \"v1\",",  
            "            \"kind\": \"Namespace\",",  
            "            \"metadata\": {",  
            "                \"creationTimestamp\": \"2018-09-26T17:33:42Z\",",  
            "                \"labels\": {",  
            "                    \"istio-injection\": \"enabled\"",  
            "                },",  
            "                \"name\": \"inventory\",",  
            "                \"resourceVersion\": \"15021\",",  
            "                \"selfLink\": \"/api/v1/namespaces/customer-inventory\",",  
            "                \"uid\": \"4fd5bfb6-c1b2-11e8-9986-8a3fc36f34\"",  
            "            },",  
            "            \"spec\": {",  
            "                \"finalizers\": [",  
            "                    \"kubernetes\"",  
            "                ]",  
            "            },",  
            "            \"status\": {",  
            "                \"phase\": \"Active\"",  
            "            }",  
            "        },",
```

I am trying to iterate through the loop and get all the values of the "name" and keep them in to a list. i have the below task . but its not working

eg values:

```
\"name\": \"test-rewards\",",

\"name\": \"inventory\",",
```

And this task:

```
- name: Show object id  
  set_fact:  
    group_object_value: "{{ (namespaces.stdout_lines | from_json).items[].metadata.name }}"   
  with_items: "{{ namespaces.stdout }}"
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Please don't post *pictures* of text. Post the text itself, properly formatted. Posting pictures makes your question less accessible, and makes it harder for someone to copy-and-paste the data in an effort to help you out. If the image you've embedded is removed from the hosting site, it also makes your question less useful to people in the future who may have the same question themselves.

Comment: I have edited the question to format the code properly. When asking your next question, take a moment to read some of the help available when entering the question; this will explain various options for formatting your code samples.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you have JSON data in the stdout of a `command` or `shell` task.  You want to use the `stdout` attribute, not `stdout_lines`; the former is a single block of text while the latter is a list, one item per line of input.  The `from_json` filter will only work with simple string variables like the `stdout` attribute.

Once you have the JSON data de-serialized, you can use the `json_query` filter to get what you want.  For example, this playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    namespaces:
      stdout: |
        {
          "apiVersion": "v1",
          "items": [
            {
              "apiVersion": "v1",
              "kind": "Namespace",
              "metadata": {
                "annotations": {
        "kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration":"{\"apiVersion\":\"v1\",\"kind\":\"Namespace\",\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{},\"labels\":{\"istio-injection\":\"enabled\"},\"name\":\"test-rewards\"}}\n"
                },
                "creationTimestamp": "2018-09-25T23:45:37Z",
                "labels": {
                  "istio-injection": "enabled"
                },
                "name": "test-rewards",
                "resourceVersion": "7399723",
                "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/test-rewards",
                "uid": "1a8e3-c11d-11e8-9986-8acd436f34"
              },
              "spec": {
                "finalizers": [
                  "kubernetes"
                ]
              },
              "status": {
                "phase": "Active"
              }
            },
            {
              "apiVersion": "v1",
              "kind": "Namespace",
              "metadata": {
                "creationTimestamp": "2018-09-26T17:33:42Z",
                "labels": {
                  "istio-injection": "enabled"
                },
                "name": "inventory",
                "resourceVersion": "15021",
                "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/customer-inventory",
                "uid": "4fd5bfb6-c1b2-11e8-9986-8a3fc36f34"
              },
              "spec": {
                "finalizers": [
                  "kubernetes"
                ]
              },
              "status": {
                "phase": "Active"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: namespaces.stdout|from_json|json_query('items[].metadata.name')
```

Will produce the following output:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "namespaces.stdout|from_json|json_query('items[].metadata.name')": [
        "test-rewards", 
        "inventory"
    ]
}
```

So if you want the variable `group_object_value` to contain those values, you would write:

```
- set_fact:
    group_object_value: "{{ namespaces.stdout|from_json|json_query('items[].metadata.name') }}"
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot @larsks