# Get the values from ansible json stdout_lines

Tags: json, ansible

Given this output

```
 "stdout_lines": [
            "[",
            "  {",
            "    \"eTag\": null,",
            "    \"id\": \"abc\",",
            "    \"location\": null,",
            "    \"name\": \"6ebba5b\",",
            "    \"properties\": {",
            "      \"actionsInfo\": null,",
            "      \"activityId\": \"f014bc98\",",
            "      \"backupManagementType\": \"load\",",
            "      \"duration\": \"0:02:59.023742\",",
            "      \"endTime\": \"2022-11-07T19:33:00.522831+00:00\",",
            "      \"entityFriendlyName\": \"SYSTEMDB [abc]\",",
            "      \"errorDetails\": null,",
            "      \"extendedInfo\": null,",
            "      \"isUserTriggered\": false,",
            "      \"jobType\": \"loadJob\",",
            "      \"operation\": \"Backup (Full)\",",
            "      \"startTime\": \"2022-11-07T19:30:01.499089+00:00\",",
            "      \"status\": \"Completed\",",
            "      \"workloadType\": \"base\"",
            "    },",
            "    \"resourceGroup\": \"abc\",",
            "    \"tags\": null,",
            "    \"type\": \"backupJobs\"",
            "  },",
            "  {",
            "    \"eTag\": null,",
            "    \"id\": \"efg\",",
            "    \"location\": null,",
            "    \"name\": \"3e6738d5\",",
            "    \"properties\": {",
            "      \"actionsInfo\": null,",
            "      \"activityId\": \"8265cb659\",",
            "      \"backupManagementType\": \"load\",",
            "      \"duration\": \"0:12:59.319233\",",
            "      \"endTime\": \"2022-11-07T19:43:00.788547+00:00\",",
            "      \"entityFriendlyName\": \"sid [abc]\",",
            "      \"errorDetails\": null,",
            "      \"extendedInfo\": null,",
            "      \"isUserTriggered\": false,",
            "      \"jobType\": \"loadJob\",",
            "      \"operation\": \"Backup (Full)\",",
            "      \"startTime\": \"2022-11-07T19:30:01.469314+00:00\",",
            "      \"status\": \"Completed\",",
            "      \"workloadType\": \"base\"",
            "    },",
            "    \"resourceGroup\": \"abc\",",
            "    \"tags\": null,",
            "    \"type\": \"backupJobs\"",
            "  },",
           "]"
        ]
```

I am trying to iterate through the loop and get all the values of the "name,entityFriendlyName and status " in a list i have the below task . but its not working

```
    - set_fact:
        name: "{{ out |from_json|json_query('.stdout_lines[].name') }}"
        entity_friendly_name: "{{ out |from_json|json_query('.stdout_lines[].properties.entityFriendlyName') }}"
        status: "{{ out |from_json|json_query('.stdout_lines[].properties.status') }}"
```

Expected answer:

eg:

"name": "6ebba5b",",
"entityFriendlyName": "SYSTEMDB [abc]"",
"status": "Completed",",

Comment: Can you provide also the task which created the JSON response? And describe in more detail what you try to achieve? Furthermore, does [Need to get the values from Ansible JSON `stdout` and put them into ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55640231/) answers some questions?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to parse some JSON output from a command, something similiar to this:

```yaml
- command: command-that-produces-json
  register: out
```

If that's the case, `out.stdout` contains a string representation of the valid JSON structure and you should use `from_json` filter on that instead.

Secondly, the `set_fact` does not make sense here, so I will make a demo using `debug` instead:

```yaml
- name: print all entities
  # You can replace the debug task with anything you wish
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg:
      name: "{{ item.name }}"
      entity_friendly_name: "{{ item.properties.entityFriendlyName }}"
      status: "{{ item.properties.status }}"
  # Loop the output and set custom label to unclutter the output
  loop: "{{ out.stdout | from_json }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.name }}"
```

This would generate:

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=6ebba5b) => {
    "msg": {
        "entity_friendly_name": "SYSTEMDB [abc]",
        "name": "6ebba5b",
        "status": "Completed"
    }
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=3e6738d5) => {
    "msg": {
        "entity_friendly_name": "sid [abc]",
        "name": "3e6738d5",
        "status": "Completed"
    }
}
```

Comment: and actually, since Ansible is really JSON capable, as soon as you have `"{{ out.stdout | from_json }}"`, you can also do `"{{ (out.stdout | from_json).name }}"`, you don't need to involve JMESPath in such 'simple' object accesses.

Comment: Indeed, JMESPath is overkill. Hence the last example which even parses the json once.

Comment: It Still gives error saying
The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'properties' or The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'name'.

Comment: Oh, I completely missed that you are using lists, my bad. In that case the `set_fact` alone does not make sense here even if you loop it because the variables would have only the last value. I've updated my task to demostrate on how to loop this.

Comment: Hi, from the above list is it possible to get the status only for "SYSTEMDB [abc]" (entity_friendly_name). If yes what will be the command?  Thankyou.